# How to delete a number of rows after finding a specific value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have a file in which the results of an analysis for a series of samples are exported one below the other. Only for some of the samples additional information that is not of interest is also exported.
This is the file structure:

```
col1 <- c('RESULTADOS','ID','result','RESULTADOS','ID','result','INFO ADICIONAL','ID','Extra','Extra2','RESULTADOS','ID','result')
col2 <- c('','1','f','','2','f','','2','q','w','','3','m')
df2 <- data.frame(col1,col2)
```

And this is the result I would like to get:

```
Datos <- c('ID','result','ID','result','ID','result')
col2 <- c('1','f','2','f','3','m')
df2 <- data.frame(Datos,col2)
```

I was wondering if there is any way in R to use a loop or some similar structure to iterate through the rows and, each time it finds a cell with "ADDITIONAL INFO" have it delete that row and the 3 following ones.
I tried filter(!Col1 c(“ADDITIONAL INFO”, Extra, Extra2)), but in that case I'm left with an ID hanging around, which I can't filter that way because I need that information in other sections.

Once those lines are discarded, I would need to be able to get it to take the value of col2 as ID when the data value is 'ID'. I tried a few ways but I just can't get to that result.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
borra <- which(col1 == "INFO ADICIONAL")
 df2[-c(borra, borra+1, borra+2, borra+3),]
```

Output:

```
         col1 col2
1  RESULTADOS     
2          ID    1
3      result    f
4  RESULTADOS     
5          ID    2
6      result    f
10 RESULTADOS     
11         ID    3
12     result    m
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data.table::shift()`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)

df2[col1 != "RESULTADOS" & !apply(df2[, shift(col1, 0:3)], 1, \(x) "INFO ADICIONAL" %in% x)]
```

Output:

```
     col1 col2
1:     ID    1
2: result    f
3:     ID    2
4: result    f
5:     ID    3
6: result    m
```